# How can I remove a row in a table using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="rep_tr0" id="row_2">
```

There is only one instance of a div with this id.  How can I remove it with jQuery? I found the following code but I am not sure how to apply this:

```
$('.widgets').find(rowId).remove();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grab by its id and then call remove.

```
 $('#row_2').remove();
```

The code you found is very similar. This says:

```
$('.widgets')    //find everything with a class of 'widgets'
  .find(rowId)   //now in all the widgets find something that has 'rowId'
  .remove();     //remove it
```

As rowId is a variable here (no quotes around it), I don't know what the intention was from the person you found it from. But it needs to be a selector that jQuery can parse. Like `#` for an id or `.` for a class.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#row_2").remove(); Should work.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a delete button in a **td** tag this works:

```
$(this).parent().parent().remove();
```

Comment: Take a look at `closest`. This is more explicit than calling multiple parents and should be just as fast. http://api.jquery.com/closest/